# __get resource in PHP "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Tags: php, arrays, object, hash, resources

I'm trying out a recipe on how to store string resources in PHP, but I can't seem to get it to work. I am a little unsure on how the __get function works in relation to arrays and objects.

Error Message: "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /var/www/html/workspace/srclistv2/Resource.php on line 34"

What am I doing wrong?

```
/**
 * Stores the res file-array to be used as a partt of the resource object.
 */
class Resource
{
    var $resource;
    var $storage = array();

    public function __construct($resource)
    {
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->load();
    }

    private function load()
    {
        $location = $this->resource . '.php';

        if(file_exists($location))
        {
             require_once $location;
             if(isset($res))
             {
                 $this->storage = (object)$res;
                 unset($res);
             }
        }
    }

    public function __get($root)
    {
        return isset($this->storage[$root]) ? $this->storage[$root] : null;
    }
}
```

Here is the resource file named QueryGenerator.res.php:

```
$res = array(
    'query' => array(
        'print' => 'select * from source prints',
        'web'  => 'select * from source web',
    )
);
```

And here is the place I'm trying to call it:

```
    $resource = new Resource("QueryGenerator.res");

    $query = $resource->query->print;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that you define `$storage` as an array in your class but then you assigne object to it in `load` method (`$this->storage = (object)$res;`).

Fields of class can be accessed with following syntax: `$object->fieldName`. So in your [`__get`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) method you should do:

```
public function __get($root)
{
    if (is_array($this->storage)) //You re-assign $storage in a condition so it may be array.
        return isset($this->storage[$root]) ? $this->storage[$root] : null;
    else
        return isset($this->storage->{$root}) ? $this->storage->{$root} : null;
}
```

Comment: @ElzoValugi Sure, it does. I use this because I _think_ it's more understandable for "non-php" programmers.

Comment: @PLB : Using this function returns NULL (from the "else"-part of the check). Still getting with "$resource->query->print" as if it where a scalar with a string.

Comment: @JonasBallestad You can access it like: `$resource->query['print']`.

Comment: @PLB So this means that going (object)$res only "objectifies" the top level, but keeps the lower ones at array behaviour?

Comment: @JonasBallestad Yes, when `$res` is an array it's exact behavior.